# UIToolbar animate alpha ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiview, uitoolbar

I have a view which has a toolbar as it's first subview (background) and then labels and imageviews on top of that. I'm trying to fade the view out but the toolbar alpha doesn't animate. It changes from 1.0 to 0.0 instantly while the other subviews animate their alpha.

I've tried disabling `allowsGroupOpacity` but it still doesn't work. In fact when I disabled that, the translucent nature of the toolbar is lost completely. It becomes transparent.

I've even tried enabling `shouldRasterize` and `rasterizationScale` but nothing works.

Anything else I can try?

**EDIT:**

I figured it out! I needed to set the `allowsGroupOpacity` to `NO` on the superview's layer and not the toolbar's layer.

Comment: You should accept this question if you answered it. Otherwise shows unanswered.

Comment: You should move your edit to an answer and mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `allowsGroupOpacity` to `NO` on the superview's layer instead of the toolbar's layer solves this issue.